# How to make subviews to maintain a non-transparent

Tags: objective-c

I get a trouble in the sense of that:

I create a UIView and set the alpha value to 0.5, and then add a subview with a alpha value in 1, when i run the app, the subview also become transparent, how to keep the subview in non-transparent?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you've noticed, setting the alpha on the parent view also affects all subviews. What I do is leave the alpha alone and use a background color with alpha for the parent view and an opaque background color for the child.

For example, in some random view controller:

```
UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
transparentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

UIView *opaqueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
opaqueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[transparentView addSubview:opaqueView];
[self.view addSubview:transparentView];
```

Comment: Does this not answer your question?

Comment: Good It works for me, but can you tell me explain me what is the difference between adding color with alpha to the parent view rather than adding alpha to the parent view.

Comment: Setting a view's background color affects only that view and is completely independent of the background color of it's children. However, alpha behaves more like the transform of a view where a rotation or scale would affect all views in the hierarchy below the transformed view.